# How to get data from another AWS db

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, blogs

I am new in AWS. I created default Blog scheme. Now I would like to create new Blog post.

Snippet for creating Post:

```
import { API } from "aws-amplify";
import { createPost,createBlog } from './graphql/mutations';


const newPost = await API.graphql({
    query: createPost,
    variables: {
        input: {
        "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "blog": /* Provide a Blog instance here */,
        "comments": [],
        "author": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    }
    }
});
```

Snippet for Creating Blog:

```
const newBlog = await API.graphql({
    query: createBlog,
    variables: {
        input: {
        "name": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "posts": []
    }
    }
});
```

My code:

How can I add Blog value in **createPost**?

```
 try {
      await API.graphql({
        query: createPost,
        variables: {
          input: {
            title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
          **  "blog": /* Provide a Blog instance here */,**
            author: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
          },
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {}
```

Comment: Could you share your graphql schema? Could you also try this via the AppSync console before creating the front-end code?

Answer (score 0):

```
type Blog @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post] @hasMany
}

type Post @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  blog: Blog @belongsTo
  comments: [Comment] @hasMany
  author: String!
}

type Comment @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  post: Post @belongsTo
  content: String!
}
```